# Am I misinterpreting something?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

Why does this function have a functional value at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

$$
f(x)=-\dfrac{a\cos{x}}{2b\cos{x}\sin{x}}
$$

Desmos shows that this function is defined at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$
with a value equal to $-\frac{a}{2b}$.

But shouldn't $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ be out of its domain?

Comment: This is the limit as $x\to\pi/2.$

Comment: It's out of its domain but the limit when $x$ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ exists.

Comment: According to standard conventions for the domain of a function when the function is defined by a formula and the domain is not explicitly stated, $\pi / 2$ is NOT in the domain of your function. However, it appears that Desmos allows algebraic simplification to occur prior to function evaluation, which results in $0/0$ cancelations taking place before evaluation. I suppose the creators of Desmos felt that doing this is overall better for the intended uses of Desmos.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Am I misinterpreting something?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ has what is called a *removable singularity* at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. What that means is that if we take the function $g(x) = -\frac{a}{2b \sin x}$, then we can say that in the neighbourhood of $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, other than the point itself, we have $f(x) = g(x)$, and so for many purposes it is convenient to ignore the discontinuity in $f$ and work with $g$ instead.

It's likely that Desmos chooses to make this simplification, even if it isn't technically correct. This might be a deliberate choice, or it might be that its graphing method doesn't have a good way to display removable singularities.